# Why if i change to INPUT_GET this code will always execute the ''else'' piece of code

Tags: php, servlet-filters

```
$num = $_POST['num'];

if(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'num', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options"=>array("min_range"=>5, "max_range"=>20)))===false) { 
    echo "Write a valid number between 5 and 20";    
} else { 
    echo 'Great, your number is: '.$num;
}
```

Comment: how are you sending the numbers to this script?

Comment: Maybe you also need to modify  $num = $_GET['num'];

Comment: it does'nt matter, when i change INPUT_POST to INPUT_GET it should return the condition FALSE

Comment: Of course I specified method="post" at HTML form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many verbs you can use to send information between your website and your app, perhaps the most commonly used are GET and POST, GET requests are the ones that you can see on the URL, usually they come after a ? symbol, POST requests on the other hand are not shown on the URL, but the data is sent "hidden", in this case you can see you're using:

`$num = $_POST['num']`

if it is working is because in your HTML page, or on the same PHP page you have something like

`<form action="mypage.php" method="post">`

so, you can get that info via _POST, not _GET, the method/verb used must match on both sides.

If you try to get the value on _GET it won't be available, so the filter will fail check on http://php.net/filter_input, it clearly states:

> or NULL if the variable_name variable is not set

you are performing a `===` comparison that won't return false, but NULL in this case, and therefor the only available code to be executed is the `else` part!

Comment: i mean when i change INPUT_POST to INPUT_GET it will take the "if" condition as TRUE and it will ecexut the "else" part of code

Comment: just completed my answer trying to explain it better

Comment: i think i got it now, it returns NULL and not false,,thanks